# Want to remove categories from top nav and only show page links

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a lot of categories and I dont want them showing on the top nav, I only want them to show in my side nav. I am wanting to have just page links on the top nav.

I do not know how to get this working, I have looked and looked and I cannot find a solution.

My top nav looks like this

[image]

Comment: You can disable that through admin > manage category > your category > include in layer navigation. Set this as no

Comment: All I have is "Include in Navigation Menu *" and when I set that to no, it removes it from the side menu as well.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done from magento admin panel you need follow following step

**Got to Admin -> Catalog -> Manage category**

and then select category which you want to hide from top nav(In your case you need to hide all so you need to select one by one and do follow step for each of them)

[image]
After select category from Manage category page go to **General Information** tab(which is by default opened) and find **Include in Navigation Menu** and set it **No** then save page

It will hide category from top nav

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely hide top menu then go to `template/page/html/header.phtml`
and find following line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

and comment it out like this:

```
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Refresh your cache and top menu should hide from your header. Hope this helps.